# R Plotly-plot layout (margind and x axis on the top)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I encountered a problem while using plotly and R shiny to visualize data. My sample codes are:

```
y <- c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7")
x1 <- c(20, 10, 15, 15, 20, 10, 15)
x2 <- c(10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10)
x3 <- c(10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5)
x4 <- c(20, 25, 25, 35, 55, 40, 35)
x5 <- c(40, 35, 35, 30, 5, 15, 35)
num <-  c(1,3,5,6,7,2,4)
df <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, num)



plot_ly(df[order(-xtfrm(df$num)),]) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x1, y = ~y, marker = list(color = 'rgb(202,0,32)'), type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x2, y = ~y,  marker = list(color = 'rgb(244,165,130)'), type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x3, y = ~y, marker = list(color = 'rgb(223,223,223)'), type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x4, y = ~y, marker = list(color = 'rgb(146,197,222)'), type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x5, y = ~y,  marker = list(color = 'rgb(5,113,176)'), type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') %>%  
  layout(title="mytitle",
         xaxis = list(title = "",
                      showticklabels = TRUE,
                      zeroline = FALSE,
                      domain = c(0.15, 1)),
         yaxis = list(title = "",
                      showticklabels = FALSE,
                      zeroline = FALSE,
                      categoryorder = 'array', 
                      categoryarray = ~qt),
         barmode = 'relative',
         paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)', plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)',
         autosize=T,
         margin = list(l = 150, r = 10, t = 100, b = 50, pad=4),
         showlegend=F) %>%
  # labeling the y-axis
  add_annotations(xref = 'paper', yref = 'y', x = 0.14, y = df$y,
                  xanchor = 'right',
                  text = df$y,
                  font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 5,
                              color = 'rgb(67, 67, 67)'),
                  showarrow = FALSE, align = 'right')
```

The problem is that the margins does not work very well with large amount of questions. In my data, one of the categories includes more than 40 questions. The plot with 5 questions looks fine. (length=500) [image: plot with 5 questions]
But the plot with over 40 questions have big top and bottom margins. (length=4000)
[image: plot with 40+ questions] 
Please help me get rid of these weird margins. 
[image: bottom margin and x-axis]
Also, I'd like to know how to put the x-axis on both the top and bottom of the plot. Thank you!

Comment: I can't really reproduce the error with your current code. If it is related to shiny, you should provide a reproducible example with shiny. But removing `domain = c(0.15, 1)` and using `yaxis = list(title = "", showticklabels = TRUE` instead and removing `add_annonation`(I don't understand why you are using it) get rid of the problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Sorry I didn't make it clear. I used these codes to make plots but the real data includes more observations (40+) than it here (5 only). 5 obs didn't make trouble but 40 obs did.